# Computer prints long strings of ssssssss sporadically

Tags: keyboard

Sometimes when I'm typing my computer prints a lot of s's, though sometimes it's other letters. It doesn't stop until you push another key (clicking doesn't stop it). I'm not sure when it does it but it happens a lot when I press Capslock+S in emacs or other text editors; I have Capslock mapped to CTRL the Gnome Tweak tool. However, it also sometimes happens when I'm not typing anything so I'm not convinced it's Ctrl+S doing it. Is there any quick fix to this?

Sorry if this has been asked before, it's difficult to google

Comment: Can you be sure it's not a physical defect of the keyboard? It reads like it also happens without even touching the `s` key, so that's unlikely. But if it only occurred after having pressed the `s` key, I would check that the key itself is not stuck in any way.

Comment: Definitely not the keyboard. I actually checked this by swapping the hard drive into a new laptop, and the problem persists

Comment: Ok, then I have no idea. I was just trying to eliminate the easiest (and only at the moment) possible reason I could think of...